# What is difference between v-app-bar and v-toolbar in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I just started exploring [vuetify](http://vuetifyjs.com/). All the vuetify componets resides in `<v-app>`.
I wanted to create menu for my site so in documentation I found `<v-app-bar>` and `<v-toolbar>`
I am confused that if I should keep menu items inside `<v-app-bar>` or `<v-toolbar>` as offical documentation says

About `<v-app-bar>` https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars

> The `v-app-bar` component is pivotal to any graphical user interface
>   (GUI), as it generally is the primary source of site navigation. The
>   app-bar component works great in conjunction with a
>   v-navigation-drawer for providing site navigation in your application.

About `<v-toolbar>` https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars

> The `v-toolbar` component is pivotal to any gui, as it generally is the
>   primary source of site navigation. The toolbar component works great
>   in conjunction with v-navigation-drawer and v-card.

Both the description are almost same. What is difference in both and when we should use what? or we should use `v-toolbar` inside `v-app-bar`?

Answer (score 35):

Per the [Vuetify Migration Guide -- 'Migrating from v1.5.x to v2.0.x'](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations#migration-guide):

> v-toolbar:  All existing scrolling techniques and app functionality
>   has been deprecated and moved to v-app-bar.

Thus, starting in Vuetify 2.0, `v-app-bar` is what you probably want to use at the top of most typical apps since you can do scrolling-related effects and designate `v-app-bar` as a unique 'top level' [application component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application#application-components) using the `app` prop.

On the other hand, `v-toolbar` could be used for other 'subordinate' cases where scrolling should definitely not affect the toolbar, perhaps if `v-toolbar` is being used as part of a in-screen widget.

Comment: why doesn't it say "deprecated" or something of the like at the very top of the toolbar doc page?

Comment: @TobiasFeil The docs are all open source if you'd like to recommend a change: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/master/packages/docs. :)

Comment: Why would anyone go through old migration documents to find something like that? It's just silly.

Comment: terrible news for newbies :-|

Comment: Doesn't look deprecated to me: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars/#extension-height Also, where's toolbar-items for v-app-bar?

Answer (score 18):

Actually `v-app-bar` extends `v-toolbar` to give you additional properties that you can use.

These properties give you far more granular control over the overall layout of the toolbar and how it responds to sizing and content changes in the surrounding space.

You can look at the properties of each and see how the `v-app-bar` has a dozen or more additional properties that you can leverage to customize the functionality and design of it, whereas the `toolbar` is opinionated about its purpose and limits those functionalities.