# Toolbar not showing on top of the page with scroll-off-screen prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, toolbar

I am trying to add `v-toolbar` for a page, where I want the toolbar to appear on screen even on scrolling. I tried using scroll-off-screen, it does show the toolbar on scrolling but when I am on top of the page the toolbar disappears. I want the toolbar to show all the time even when I am on top of the page or I am scrolling. I am using Vuetify version 1.0.5.

```html
<template> 
  <div>
    <v-toolbar dense fixed class="main-toolbar" scroll-off-screen>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md4 class="sub-main-page">
          <v-toolbar-title><a class="toolbar-styling" href="javascript:document.getElementById('section1').scrollIntoView(true);">Section 1</a></v-toolbar-title>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md4 class="sub-main-page">
          <v-toolbar-title><a class="toolbar-styling" href="javascript:document.getElementById('section2').scrollIntoView(true);">Section 2</a></v-toolbar-title>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md4 class="sub-main-page">
          <v-toolbar-title><a class="toolbar-styling" href="javascript:document.getElementById('section3').scrollIntoView(true);">Section 3</a></v-toolbar-title>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-toolbar>
    <div id="section1">
     <Section1></Section1>
    </div>
    <div id="section1">
     <Section2></Section2>
    </div>
    <div id="section1">
     <Section3></Section3>
    </div>
  </div>    
</template>

<script>
import Section1 from 'views/section1.vue';
import Section2 from 'views/section2.vue';
import Section3 from 'views/section3.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Section1,
    Section2,
    Section3,
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `fixed` and `scroll-off-screen` props are not intended for `v-toolbar`. Rather you should use those props with [`v-app-bar`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#api) instead of `v-toolbar`, since the [latter is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651469/6277151) in 2.x.

To keep the toolbar fixed at the top of the page:

```html
<v-app-bar fixed>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-drake-dkkv9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FDemo.vue&theme=dark)